# How to use default value on Ranorex UI when we call a method with int parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, default, wait, ranorex

In Ranorex tool have one wait method with 3 parameters of strung, int, int

When I call same method in Ranorex UI by default it is taking '0' and when I try to remove it is not accepting

I'm using Ranorex tool for one of desktop app and we are using wait method  with 3 parameters 1 with required repoitem , 2 int type with default meantime and 3 int type with max time...like below
public void wait(Repoitem repo, int mintime=0 int maxtime=80)

When I call same method in Ranorex UI by default it is taking '0' and when I try to remove it is not accepting,because of this whatever the condition inside my method it is taking values which are on Ranorex UI not the default values

Is there any way in Ranorex to call a method on UI with out any default values